# The Command "File.BatchNewTeamProject" is not available in VSTS 2010

Tags: tfs, command, devenv

I am trying to automate the creation of team projects using a command built into VS 2010 called File.BatchNewTeamProject using a project settings file as an argument, and executing this as a process silently in the background from my c# win app. I am aware of a requirement that Team Explorer has to be open and connected to TFS before this command can run, however, when I start a process with devenv.exe, a fresh instance of visual studio pops up with Team Explorer not connected by default. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I added an extra command statement and the whole thing started working.

devenv /command view.TeamExplorer /command "File.BatchNewTeamProject "C:\vss2TeamFoundation\ProjectCreation\Ajax.xml

Answer (score 0):

Just posted this project on Codeplex: http://tfsprojprovisioner.codeplex.com/

Includes an assembly that hides BatchNewTeamProject behind a simple programmatic interface, and a sample desktop app that you can use to create and provision new Team Projects.  Must be run on a computer that has VS 2010 installed, and by a user that has permissions to create new projects.  But it doesn't require you to interact with VS directly, at all.